# where is mm_teleop package?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In  [PR2 workshop](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Events/PR2BetaTraining), there is gripper python script call mm_teleop package.

```
  roslib.load_manifest('mm_teleop')
```

Where is mm_teleop?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12506/where-is-mm_teleop-package?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like mm_teleop was a package that the tutorial user was supposed to create as part of the Moving Mechanism tutorial: [Tuesday](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Events/PR2BetaTraining#Tuesday) and [pdf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Events/PR2BetaTraining?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=moving_mechanism.pdf)

You can create it with:

```
roscreate-pkg mm_teleop rospy pr2_controllers_msgs actionlib geometry_msgs
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2